# Conditionally install files based on Command Line Argument during WIX Install

Tags: properties, wix, installation, command-line-arguments, conditional-statements

I am wanting to install files during a wix install conditionally whether a command line parameter has been set

e.g. I have the following file, which only installs if a DEBUG flag has been set

```
    <Component Id="file.pdb" Guid="SOME-GUID">
       <Condition>DEBUG</Condition>
       <File Id="file.pdb" Source="file.pdb" KeyPath="yes" Vital="no" />
    </Component>
```

I have added the DEBUG property and read it in from the command line. The File never installs though, I am perplexed as to why?

Comment: How exactly did you set the DEBUG property on the command line? Perhaps there is something wrong there.

Comment: As an aside, you only need to specify the `Source` attribute for the `File` element in your example. The rest of the file attributes can be inferred by wix. Also, the component guid can be omitted. Wix will automatically generate a stable GUID.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem, looking into now. I have my files in merge modules. I am getting the property from the main wxs which builds the msi, but i fear i may have to get the property from every single msm... just testing my theory now, will let you know my findings

Comment: it sounds like you may be confusing Windows Installer properties with wix preprocessor variables. That's why I asked how you are setting the DEBUG property.

Comment: solved the issue. it was that i wasnt passing in the cmd line args to the seperate modules. will add my answer now with some more details for others to see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue. Below is an explanation of what I was doing wrong and what I did to solve it

I had created an installer (.msi) and was using the following cmd line args to start it up

> msiexec -i prog.msi DEBUGPROPERTY=True

I had several merge modules with components which would install depending on whether this property was set which were getting the property injected into them like so...

```
<Merge
    Id="SomeID"
    Language="1033"
    SourceFile="Module.msm"
    DiskId="1">
    <ConfigurationData
      Name="debugProperty"
      Value="[DEBUGPROPERTY]" />
```

What I was missing was in the merge modules (.msm) i needed the following code

```
    <Configuration Name='debugProperty' Format='Text' DefaultValue='[DEBUGPROPERTY]'/>
    <Substitution Table='CustomAction' Row='setDebugProperty' Column='Target' Value='[=debugProperty]'/>
    <CustomAction Id='setDebugProperty' Property='DEBUGPROPERTY' Value='[DEBUGPROPERTY]'/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action='setDebugProperty' Before="LaunchConditions">1</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This allowed me to access the property DEBUGPROPERTY inside this module so i could restrict whether a file was installed at install time or not, like so

```
<Component Id="File.pdb" Guid="SOME-GUID">
    <Condition>DEBUGPROPERTY</Condition>
    <File Id="File.pdb" Source="File.pdb" KeyPath="yes" Vital="no" />
</Component>
```

This now works, and allows me to install .pdb files during an install if i include this argument.